# Does supported android apps in Delphi XE6 with Qualcomm-Snapdragon-800-MSM8974?

Tags: android, delphi, arm, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

Android Devices Supported for Application Development
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development and

•Processor: 2,2 GHz X 4 (Snapdragon 800) http://www.generalmobile.com/discoveryElite.html

but http://system-on-a-chip.findthebest.com/compare/34-297/ARM-Cortex-A15-MPCore-vs-Qualcomm-Snapdragon-800-MSM8974

There isn't neon simd in Qualcomm-Snapdragon-800-MSM8974

Does supported android apps in Delphi XE6 with Qualcomm-Snapdragon-800-MSM8974?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It uses a Krait 400 CPU which says it has NEON.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krait_%28CPU%29